# how to make a collider high luminosity?

Tags: large-hadron-collider

Exactly what procedures are followed to increase the luminosity of a particle collider? Say when LHC increases its luminosity, does it increase the number of protons per bunch? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

Luminosity is literally the number of particles, so yes, putting in more of them increases the luminosity.

I think you are perhaps confusing the luminosity of a particular experiment with the *maximum* luminosity the accelerator can handle. The former is just how much stuff they put in, the later is a function of the design itself.